# Active Directory: Accessing network share as WinXP SYSTEM user

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, permissions, windows-xp, network-share

### The Problem:

I cannot access a `Domain Computers`-accesible network share by a process running on Windows XP as a `SYSTEM` account.

I've got a 2008R2 domain, a 2003R2 file server and a set of clients.

On the file server, I've made a share accessible by the `Domain Computers` group. The share is supposed to hold a read-only repository of files ([Wpkg](http://wpkg.org/)) to be accessed from domain workstations by a system service ([Wpkg-GP](https://code.google.com/p/wpkg-gp/)) run by `SYSTEM` user.

Now the problem is that, while it works perfectly on Windows 7, **it completely fails on Windows XP**. It seems, that for some reason the `SYSTEM` account on Windows XP cannot authenticate as a computer. See more in details.

### The Question:

What do I do wrong?

Is it perhaps a natural behaviour of Windows XP system? If so, can it be changed or fixed? Or is there any other way to achieve a scenario, in which a network share would be visible to the `SYSTEM` user on computers, without being accessible by the users?

### The Details:

- The `Domain Computers` group has received permissions **both for the files and for the share**
- I have checked higher permissions, all the way from `Read` to `Full Controll`
- I have tested the issue with fresh, out-of-the-box operating systems installed on VBox

Since the problem was reported by application, I first began to verify actual `SYSTEM` user rights. On both Windows versions (7 and XP) I have opened an elevated `cmd` session impersonating `SYSTEM` account (using `PsExec -s -i cmd.exe`) and attempted to manually mount the network share :

```
net use x: \\myfs.mydomain.com\Wpkg
```

On Windows 7, the drive has been mounted without demur. But on Windows XP the command responded with information about incorrect password and a prompt for new one:

```
[Windows XP]
Password for \\myfs.mydomain.com\Wpkg is incorrect.

Please enter password for "myfs.mydomain.com": _
```

*(please note that this is only a translation, an official english locale may sound differently)*

Comment: ist there a reason why you don't want to use the wpkg-gp feature to use a different account than SYSTEM to access the network shares?

Comment: Most important reason is that I would have to deploy these credentials openly via GPO, which wouldn't be entirely secure.

Comment: Also, the current setup works well with Windows 7 and I hope there is nothing against it working in older system. And another important thing - I've attempted to try to push these credentials to XP selectively (via Wpkg-GP GPO adm pack), yet - suprisingly - it did not change anything on the XP systems. I'm not exactly sure if this feature works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FIXED!

The source of the problem was the **fileserver not registering itself into DC DNS**. It seems it was apparently done by someone on purpose - the corresponding network interface option has been manually unchecked:

```
(network interface) 
  -> Properties 
    -> TCP/IP Protocol 
      -> Advanced 
        -> DNS 
          -> [ ] Register this connection's address in DNS
```

After checking the above option and issuing `ipconfig /registerdns`:

- fileserver registered properly in DC DNS records
- Windows XP `SYSTEM` user began to properly mount the problematic share without being asked for credentials

The different behaviour of Windows XP and Windows 7 must be due to some difference in internal implementation; I'd guess Kerberos, though my knowledge of Kerberos is yet superficial.

---

I find it interesting enough to add, that a quite similar thing happens when I try to add a `CNAME` record from ie. `wpkg.domain.mydomain.com` to `filesystem.domain.mydomain.com`:

In Windows XP only the final host name works:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir \\wpkg[.domain.mydomain.com]\wpkg
Access denied.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir \\fileserver[.domain.mydomain.com]\wpkg
[...result OK... ]
```

...while on Windows 7 there is nothing against using CNAME:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir \\wpkg[.domain.mydomain.com]\wpkg
[...result OK... ]

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir \\fileserver[.domain.mydomain.com]\wpkg
[...result OK... ]
```

Note that here I got an `Access denied` error, not a password prompt.

Comment: Great that you figured it out! Regarding the CNAME not working, I know by default Windows will only allow SMB connections using the server's name or IP. If you manage to route an SMB request with a different name (like a CNAME), Windows will reject the request. You can use the `DisableStrictNameChecking` setting to disable this behavior to allow CNAME's. Keep in mind though that Kerberos will never be used in this configuration.

Comment: So it seems that the Win7 machine is falling back to NTLM but the XP won't? Seems odd. And if so, it almost seems that maybe that same person already set `DisableStrictNameChecking`? Or used one of the methods here: http://www.marc-lognoul.me/itblog-en/post/2010/09/08/Multiple-Names-for-a-File-and-Print-Server-Running-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx? If you troubleshoot this any further I'd be interested to see what you find. Good luck!

Comment: __Worth remembering:__ It seems that the `Register this connection's address in DNS` setting is __unchecked by default__ if you assign a static (non-DHCP) IP address to the server.

Comment: I'll by trying with proper `CNAME` registering as soon as I get a final, production machine for my fileserver :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's a default behavior. Looking at my VM's (XP, Win7, 2003 R2, 2008 R2, 2012), all have retained the option as checked even though they are configured statically. Could this be caused by the method of how they were set statically? Maybe via an OS deployment? I know you mentioned this is an inherited environment, who knows what other surprises you're going to discover!

Answer (score 1):

In a normal, vanilla environment, what your doing will work. I can't replicate what you're seeing. I created a share (\\server\share), granted Domain Computers Read access, and removed all other ACE's. Running under `psexec -s -i -d cmd`, I'm able to access the share from both the XP and Win7 computers.

How certain are you that the XP computer is a member of Domain Computers? By default, all new computer accounts are members of Domain Computers not via the `member` (or `memberOf`) attribute, but instead as the object's Primary Group. The Domain Computers group's well-known RID is 515. That RID value is stamped on the computer object's primaryGroupID attribute.

Can you take a look at the computer object's primaryGroupID and memberOf attributes and let me know what, if anything, is present? For that matter, if you're comfortable you could post the full output for an XP and Win7 computer? Either way, an easy way to get the info is with the following command: `dsquery * -filter "name=COMPUTER_NAME_GOES_HERE" -attr *`.

Something else to try would be changing the ACL on the share/NTFS, one at a time, to allow `Everyone`, `Authenticated Users`, `Domain Users`, and the computer's name itself. Try each and see which, if any, work.

Comment: Both computers have `primaryGroupID=515`. I have compared a complete list of computer attributes and the only thing that is significantly different between Windows XP and Windows 7 is that the XP lacks `servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/COMPUTER` and `servicePrincipalName: RestrictedKrbHost/COMPUTER.domain.mydomain.com` entries.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I found some more, err... interesting stuff about my domain:

Comment: It is worth to point, that my DNS structure contains a `mydomain.com`  (with linux DNS servers, out of my jurisdiction) and `domain.mydomain.com` (managed by two DCs). Funny thing is that workstations get `mydomain.com` NS adresses from DHCP and it even works, eg. they find the correct, domain NS and are able to write their SPNs correctly to the `domain.mydomain.com` zone...

Comment: ...yet the fileserver, which has static IP & DNS configuration, points directly to DC DNS. And... this fileserver is actually not listed in DC DNS. This server has an A record configured in `mydomain.com` (let's say `fs.mydomain.com`) and that one works, yet `fs.domain.mydomain.com` fails to resolve.

Comment: I have made an additional test - I used another domain-connected server (HyperV host) to make a share. This server, 2008R2, shows properly in DC DNS and... Windows XP SYSTEM user mounts it properly :)

Comment: Any ideas what may be wrong with 2003R2 fs then? :)